# Trying to get AirPods working in Ubuntu 21.10 on my 2012 MacBook Air, but little seems to work

Tags: bluetooth, 21.10

I’ve already done a ton of searching trying to find solutions to this issue, and the most common fix seems to be changing the controller mode in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf to either bredr or dual, and then restarting the Bluetooth service. However, this did nothing for me. The result is always the same: I open the Bluetooth setup in settings (I’ll use KDE’s as an example), I attempt to connect, it tells me that it failed to connect, and although the device appears in my paired Bluetooth devices, trying to connect to it instantly lands me the message “protocol not available”.

I did also manage to connect it (only once), and the earbud controls let me send a play or pause command, but it wouldn’t appear on my actual audio device output list, so I couldn’t output audio to the earbuds.

Does anyone possibly know why this could be happening, and does anyone perhaps even have a fix for it?

Thanks.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKL3O.png)

Comment: First hit by using a search machine delivers [this](https://reckoning.dev/blog/airpods-pro-ubuntu/) - does it help?

Comment: No. I attempted the steps on this site multiple times before even asking the question here, but to no avail.

Comment: I found a half solution (not marking this as an answer because it doesn't really address the issue directly). Although, no matter what I tried, my Airpods wouldn't work on that installation, trying them on another computer with Ubuntu recently installed does work, via the instructions from that website sent above. It's also possible that unpairing them from your last device helps, but I don't really know. This also worked on a Kubuntu (what I use) live CD on the problematic device, and since I've already been planning on reinstalling my system for other reasons, that's what I'll do.